# Issue with Self Signed Cert in WCF - Must have Private Key

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I am creating a WCF service hosted within IIS7 on Windows Vista SP1. I am getting the following error:

The certificate 'CN=SignedByLocalHost' must have a private key that is capable of key exchange. The process must have access rights for the private key.

It looks like I would need to give the host process assess to the certificate which was done in the past with winhttpcertcfg which has been deprecated for Vista. The article I found indicates to use the certificate console, but I am missing somethign because I don't see any capability to edit my cert.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IIS 7.0/7.5
Just Start->Run ->inetmgr
Select the server
Under "Security" panel, go to "Server Certificates"
In the left pane click - "Create Self Signed Certificate" and complete the process
The crtfiticate will get installed in **LocalMachine** StoreLocation under **Personal** storename.
Now use this certificate in your WCF service and you will not face this error

Comment: That's a heck of a lot easier, then my way. My way is the old IIS6 approach

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.

Assuming you have a self signed cert at c:\OutCert the following command will work. I had left off the -sky exchange.

makecert -sk SignedByCA -iv c:\OutCert.pvk -n "CN=MyLocalHost" -ic c:\OutCert.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss My -sky exchange pe

Now you can go into the MMC tool and manage the private keys and grant IIS access to the key. To manage private keys, right-click on the certificate and select `All Tasks / Manage Private Keys`.

Comment: Explain please - in detail how you go to the MMC tool and manage the private keys?

Comment: Where is this All Tasks/Manage Private Keys? I am running Windows 2008 R2, and I don't see that option in the MMC Snap in...

Comment: @essedbl: If you right-click on a certificate in the MMC Certificates snap-in, then click on All Tasks, and all you see is Open and Export..., then double-click on the certificate and you won't see any mention of a private key -- there is none attached. Try a certificate in Personal, which says, "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate" on the General tab, and then try right-click "All Tasks", and you'll see the "Manage Private Keys...". It's only displayed if a private key is there to be managed.

Comment: If you still don't see "Manage Private Keys...", make sure you're using the 'Computer account' certificate store and not the 'My user account' store when loading the MMC snap-in.

Comment: The "Manage Private Keys" option is only found under LocalMachine/StoreName. You won't find it under CurrentUser/.. or Service/.. , at least not in Win7. But once you perform the management, you can then export or copy the certs to other stores (like Currentuser / Service) and it should retain the same rights.

Comment: If your on Windows 7 follow the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is coming to this question because can't find the "Manage Private Keys" option, the response given by [Crackerjack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344590/issue-with-self-signed-cert-in-wcf-must-have-private-key/76870579#comment12312085_344643) solved it for me:

> "make sure you're using the 'Computer account' certificate store and
> not the 'My user account' store when loading the MMC snap-in"