# Is it possible to force the WCF test client to accept a self-signed certificate?

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed, wcftestclient

I have a WCF web service running in IIS 7 using a self-signed certificate (it's a proof of concept to make sure this is the route I want to go). It's required to use SSL.

Is it possible to use the WCF Test Client to debug this service without needing a non-self-signed certificate?

When I try I get this error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   https:///Service1.svc
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation service to which you have
>   access, please check that you have
>   enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling
>   metadata publishing, please refer to
>   the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata
>   Exchange Error    URI:
>   https:///Service1.svc
>   Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'https:///Service1.svc'.
>   Could not establish trust relationship
>   for the SSL/TLS secure channel with
>   authority ''.    The
>   underlying connection was closed:
>   Could not establish trust relationship
>   for the SSL/TLS secure channel.    The
>   remote certificate is invalid
>   according to the validation
>   procedure.HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   https:///Service1.svc
>   There was an error downloading
>   'https:///Service1.svc'.
>   The underlying connection was closed:
>   Could not establish trust relationship
>   for the SSL/TLS secure channel.    The
>   remote certificate is invalid
>   according to the validation procedure.

EDIT: This question is specifically about using the **WCF Test Client** to test a web service already secured via SSL using a self-signed certificate. The server is already set up to accept any certificate provided, it's the WCF Test Client I don't see a way to do this for.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a non self-signed certificate in development area and then use this certificate in IIS for applying the SSL. The steps are:

1. Create self-signed certificate

   ```
   makecert -r -pe -n "CN=My Root Authority" -a sha1 -sky signature 
       -ss CA -sr CurrentUser  
       -cy authority 
       -sv CA.pvk CA.cer
   ```
2. Create a non self-signed certificate for SSL which signed by this root certificate and then create pfx-file from that

   ```
   makecert -pe -n "CN=servername" -a sha1 -sky exchange
       -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic CA.cer -iv CA.pvk
       -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
       -sy 12 -sv server.pvk server.cer

   pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx
   ```

now you just need to import the `server.pfx` into the IIS and setup the web site binding to use this certificate and also install the `CA.cer` in `Local Computer` \ `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` store in both server and client by doing this WCF client would work with the service through HTTPS without any problem.

Comment: You beauty! one more trick is you may get an invalid password error which you can solve by passing the password on the commandline on the last line: pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -pi "yourpw" -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx -po "yourpw"

Comment: I got an error about an incorrect password when adding the pfx on the server, but I just skipped typing in a password and all seemed to be ok.

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to do this if you replace the WCF Test Client with [WCFStorm Lite Edition](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx).  It's free and is quite a bit more flexible than MS's test client... for example, it'll let you specify a user name & password if you're doing username authentication.

Comment: If you're like me, and don't like downloading software you've never heard of, here's the Visual Studio magazine review of WFCStorm.  http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/10/29/free-tool-wcfstorm.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344590/issue-with-self-signed-cert-in-wcf-must-have-private-key) helped in my case. Be sure to use *exact* machine name as certificate expects. For exampe `machine/service.svc` may not work, while `machine.domain/service.svc` - works.

Comment: Mine was the other way (as in machine.domain failed while machine just worked). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question... here is how you force your WCF test client to accept a self-signed certificate...

```
        using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
        {
            System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback callBack = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += callBack;

            Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(35));

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= callBack;
        }
```

Comment: I think he meant the _WCFTestClient.exe_. Whatever, your answer helped me with my WCF test client **Project**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Just download the generated WSDL from the service (https://localhost/Service1.svc?singleWsdl) and supply the path to this file when adding a service in the WCF Test Client.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after adding a `https` binding to my site in IIS and choosing the **IIS Express Development Certificate**.

It turned out that for `https` to work I also had to input the **host name** for the binding. In my case `localhost`.

[image: Edit Site Binding]

Answer (score -4):

You can supply your own method to validate the certificate.

Try this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(EasyCertCheck);
```

The call back:

```
bool EasyCertCheck(object sender, X509Certificate cert,
        X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any way to add this code to the WCF Test Client (code which I do not control). I have already added this call to my own code (server side).

Comment: Of course, this is exactly the right approach if you are trying to force any other C# WCF client to accept a self-signed security certificate.