# WPF WebBrowser control ssl issue

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

How to disable SSL checking when using System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser control inside a WPF application?

I have tried to use the ServicePointManager but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the typical approach of [hooking the validation callback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10345519/656243) not work?

Comment: No. The callback is not firing.