# WCF client https request

Tags: wcf, ssl, soap

I am trying to send SOAP message to endpoint starting with HTTPS. This is one way SSL, so I should not need certificate to send request.

While using the config from below I get following exception:

```
Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'some.domain.com/endpoint'.
```

I tried many different transport settings, sometimes it asks for username or certification in ClientCredentials, but hey - I should not need them! I could visit the requested endpoint via browser window without any authentication.
Am I missing something in configuration? I feel a little confused right now.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="PublisherBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
    </binding>       
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://some.domain.com/endpoint"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PublisherBinding"
    contract="PublisherContract" name="NotificationsEndpoint"/>
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately wcf test client does not support invalid certificates. you can make it work like this [Is it possible to force the WCF test client to accept a self-signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792539/is-it-possible-to-force-the-wcf-test-client-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate) or you can use [wcfstorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx). second solution is better.